# A mathematical object that can be characterised by axioms as well as by universal constructions

Tags: axioms, universal-property

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316974/axioms-vs-universal-constructions-properties) question (more specifically one of the comments) prompted me to ask this question: Can someone give me an example of a mathematical object that one can characterize both via axioms and universal constructions ?

(Please note, that I yet don't have any background in category theory whatsoever, so the only place I came in contact with universal constructions was during an intro course in abstract algebra. So I know how to characterize the field of fractions for example with a universal construction, but generally know very little about universal contructions - I only have a vague intuition about them, which I described more or less in the question I linked)

Comment: I don't understand: why can't you just call the universal property an axiom? (Here I'm assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that by "universal construction" you mean "universal property", because I don't know what a "universal construction" is.)

Comment: @NoahStein Yes, I assume universal construction is a universal property. Well, you're right! But I was more thinking of examples of things that we define by axioms that aren't already a description of a universal property. Since this question is already a favourite one of two people, I assume there is some interest in such examples.